# Linq an aggregate with a grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm translating a query and here's the original:

```
select top 5 t.usrID, u.FirstName, u.LastName, t.cnt as sCount
from (
    select usrID, COUNT(rID) as cnt
    from sessions as s where s.sDate > DATEADD(yy, -1, getdate())
    group by usrID
) as t
    inner join users as u on t.usrID = u.usrID
order by t.cnt desc
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
var topUser = (from p in _context.Sessions
               where p.SDate > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
               join c in _context.Users on p.UsrId equals c.UsrId into j1
               from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
              // group j2 by p.UsrId into grouped
               select new
               {
                   p.UsrId,
                   j2.FirstName,
                   j2.LastName,
                   cnt = p.RId
               })
                //.OrderBy(d => d.cnt)
                //.GroupBy(o => o.UsrId)
               .Take(5);
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to include `count()` and `group by` clauses. When I include `groupBy` my other columns disappear. Thank you.

Comment: the `GroupBy` in linq will return `IQueryable` with only the grouping key and its members.

Comment: When you're translating SQL to LINQ, it helps if you start by structuring the query the same way. Your SQL has `FROM (...) AS t`,  where "(...)" is a derived table. You have no comparable expression in the C# code, which would look like `from t in (...)` where `(...)` is a LINQ expression for the derived table portion.

Comment: @madreflection I think so it is not perfect solve. Cause you operate O(N*N) times. Can you explain me İf i wrong ?

Comment: @EminNiftiyev: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding your question, but O(N*N) aka O(N^2) is not the issue here.

Comment: This is very bad way to approach it. You are not *translating* the query into LINQ. You are developing LINQ statement that will have the same functionality as you legacy SQL statement. In order to do that, you first have to design the model. It may simplify if you can scaffold the model from the database. Once you do that - writing LINQ statement will be much easier. Looks like you already have `Users` and `Sessions` Models. Could you please share those in the question. Finally, if you have `join` in LINQ statement - it's big code smell. You must be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
           var topUser = (from p in _context.Sessions
           where p.SDate > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1)
           join c in _context.Users on p.UsrId equals c.UsrId into j1
           from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
           group j2 by p.UsrId into g
           select new
           {
               UsrId = g.Key,
               FirstName = g.Select(x => x.FirstName).FirstOrDefault(),
               LastName = g.Select(x => x.LastName).FirstOrDefault(),
               sCount = g.Count()
           })
           .OrderByDescending(d => d.sCount)
           .Take(5);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer to your answer - not to your original query. I would put it as comment, but without formatting it's hard to explain
Assuming `User` object has collection of `Session` your first statement can be drastically simplified:

```
var topUsers = _context.Sessions
        .Where(s => s.SDate > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
        .Select(s => new
        {
            s.UsrId,
            cnt = s.User.Sessions.Count(u => u.UsrId == s.UsrId)
        })
        .OrderByDescending(s => s.cnt)
        .Take(5);
```

You can shape the results to get a ViewModel that also has FirstName and LastName. It all boils down to defining a model with one-to-many relationship

Answer (score 0):

Alright so it's not the most efficient but it works:

```
var topUsers = _context.Sessions
                .Where(s => s.SDate > DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1))
                .GroupBy(s => s.UsrId)
                .Select(ws => new { ws.Key, cnt = ws.Count() })
                .OrderByDescending(s => s.cnt)
                .Take(5);

var topNamedUsers = topUsers.Join(_context.Users, ws => ws.Key, ud => ud.UsrId, (ws, ud) => new { ws.Key, ud.FirstName, ud.LastName, ws.cnt });
```